# auto approve comments in the posts of a specific category wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I had used this code to automatically approve comments of a specific category but after the last update wordpress 4.4 this code not work:

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_comment_moderation', 'auto_aprove_posts_b' );
add_filter( 'pre_option_comment_whitelist', 'auto_aprove_posts_b' );

function auto_aprove_posts_b( $option ) 
{  
    if( in_category( '20' ) )
    return 0;

    return $option;
}
```

do you know how to automatically approve comments in the posts of a specific category?

Comment: Just reproduced, worked on 4.3 and does not on 4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Huge Disclaimer* - I didn't write this solution. Credit goes to https://www.nosegraze.com/approve-comments-category/. She actually answers this very question so not sure why the answer is not posted here.

Anyway, this will do the same thing:

```
function auto_approve_comments_in_category( $approved, $commentdata ) {
        $cat_id = 10; // This needs to be the ID of the category you want to approve.

        // If the post being commented on is in our category, always approve the comment.
        if( in_category( $cat_id, $commentdata['comment_post_ID'] ) ) {
            return 1;
        }

        // Otherwise, return the original approval status.
        return $approved;
    }

add_filter( 'pre_comment_approved' , 'auto_approve_comments_in_category' , '99', 2 );
```

Note that this is a filter from the Akismet plugin so this would need to be active for this to work.